# Strings from default locale missing from Django JavaScript catalog

Tags: javascript, django, django-i18n

### Problem

The problem I am having is that the JavaScript catalog doesn't include fallback strings in certain scenarios. In other words: when string "A" is not translated in `es_MX` but it is translated in `es`, the JavaScript catalog contains the default or untranslated "A" string.

I set up an app that demonstrates this problem: https://github.com/cmermingas/i18n_test

### Setup

- `LOCALE_PATHS` set to `PROJECT_ROOT/locale`.
- Translations for all apps stored under `LOCALE_PATHS`.
- `JavaScriptCatalog` configured without packages:

```
path('jsi18n/', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog')
```

- `es_MX` and `es` translations that demonstrate the problem:

  - The string `"es - Not translated"` is translated in the `es` locale.
  - The string `"es_MX - Not translated"` is translated in the `es_MX` locale.

### Workaround

This works if I pass `packages` to `JavaScriptCatalog`:

```
path(
    'jsi18n/',
    JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(packages=["testapp"]),
    name='javascript-catalog'
)
```

But this is not required, is it?

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69800439/6118299), which suggests adding `domain="django"`, but it didn't work for me.

What am I doing wrong or is this an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was identified as a bug in [issue #33863](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33863) and a fix was submitted. The solution will be to update Django when this fix is released.

As a workaround, I suggest what I noted in the question (pass `packages` to `JavaScriptCatalog`):

```
path(
    'jsi18n/',
    JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(packages=["<your-app-here>"]),
    name='javascript-catalog'
)
```